# Angular routing params issue with uri

Tags: angularjs

what I can do with this:

I have:

`appPath/courses` - list

`appPath/courses/:id` - route with param

`appPath/courses/add` - route to add new course

And when I type `appPath/courses/add` it going to `appPath/courses/:id` `.when` clausule.

How to fix that?

`.when("/courses", {
                templateUrl: "App/courses/index/view.html",
                controller: "CoursesIndexCtrl"
            })
            .when("/courses/add", {
                templateUrl: "App/courses/add/view.html",
                controller: "AddCourseCtrl"
            })
            .when("/courses/:id", {
                templateUrl: "App/courses/details/view.html",
                controller: "CourseDetailsCtrl"
            })`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order:

```
appPath/courses - list
appPath/courses/add - route to add new course
appPath/courses/:id - route with param
```

Comment: Do not fix the problem.

Comment: Could you please add more code, so I can see if there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`/courses/:id` and `/courser/add` are quite the same for the router. you will ending up overwriting either one or another.

give up on one othe those routes and adopt a longer path, for example:

```
/courses/add
/courses/detail/:id
```

Comment: /courses/:id/detail would probably be more semantically effective